# GRAV - Custom form pages for login plugin

Tags: grav

I want full control of custom login, register, etc. pages in Grav. Default form plugin does not allow to do things such as two columns, etc.

I have been checking documentation for login plugin but it does not seem to be any example on how to provide a fully custom page for those forms.

Is there any place where an example is given?

For example, how a user_register form shall be prepared as a custom page or template to interact with login plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The login plugin creates the login page from 3 template files. Simply putting the matching template files in your theme folder will override the template that comes in the plugin. In the plugin, you'll see the following files:

```
- templates /
  - login.html.twig
  - partials /
    - messages.html.twig
    - login-form.html.twig
```

`login.html.twig` inherits the `base` template and call `messages.html.twig` and `login-form.html.twig`.